# Why the Sleep executes first and than the code above it in android?

Tags: java, android

Why is the try block executed first, i want the colors to change first and then it should sleep fo 5000ms. i mean the system sleeps before the colors changes.
private OnClickListener CheckAnswer =new OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        disableButtons();
        Button incoming=(Button) arg0;
        if(incoming.getText().toString().equals(Q.getAnswer()))
        {
            incoming.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            correct++;
            score+=15;
        }
        else 
        {
            incoming.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            wrong++;
            if(C1.getText().toString().equals(Q.getAnswer()))
                C1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if(C2.getText().toString().equals(Q.getAnswer()))
                C2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if(C3.getText().toString().equals(Q.getAnswer()))
                C3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            modifyScore();

        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        questionGenerator();
    }
};`
```

Comment: I'm not shure, but maybe you have to redraw your element after changing the color.

Comment: Why would you want to sleep the UI-thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd guess because the properties of the view are updated, but the screen redraw is stuck behind your sleep. DO NOT sleep on the main thread.

Instead create a Handler in the onCreate of your Activity and post a delayed Runnable to it.

```
private Handler mHandler;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mHandler = new Handler();
}
...
private OnClickListener CheckAnswer = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View view) {
       // fix up view
       mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               questionGenerator();
           }
       }, 10000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept his answer if it solved your question!

Answer (score 2):

You're working on the GUI's main thread (what in Swing is called the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)), which is the same thread that also does the updating. So the sequence is:

1. Set the new background color
2. Sleep 10 seconds
3. `onClick` returns
4. the main thread has a chance to update the component

I think you'll find that not only does the background color not change, but your whole UI will seem frozen until the `Thread.sleep` is done.

You need to do your main work on another thread (I don't know Android, but in Swing you can use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)), so that the thread is free to do its tasks, including updating the component.

Comment: Swing? Android doesn't use Swing.

Comment: yeah android doesnt use swing

Comment: The principles are similar though I imagine (never used Swing). Android has an event-dispatch thread like yshavit is referencing. This is also the Thread that drawing/UI updates are done on. Commonly in Android this is referred to as the "UI Thread" or (more properly) the "main Thread".

Comment: Serves me right for answering when I only half-know. ;) I updated the post to make it generic enough to apply to what I'm guessing Android has, while keeping the links to the EDT in case some future traveler finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't sleep in your UI thread of you'll get a Force Close.  Second, the actually (re)painting of the controls cannot happen until the OnClickListener ends.

Comment: @Art : See the answer from cygnus about using the `postDelayed` method of `Handler`.