# Animating crossfade between 2 layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to implement an animation which crossfades between 2 layout, with a layover between them. The first layout is the main layout, the second is a simple linear layout with textView and red background (your classic "Wrong!" screen if you will...). My goal is to animate a quick transition between the mainLayout and wrongLayout, have the program wait for a short period of time while displaying the wrongLayout and then automatically return to mainLayout. This turns out to be extremelly hard, I've tried using monitors, Thread.sleep() etc. but what I get is that the program waits before starting the animation and THEN performs it without any layover.

My code is as follows:

In the main method-

```
LinearLayout wrongLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrong_layout);
            RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

            int animationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
                    android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime);

            crossfade(wrongLayout, mainLayout, animationDuration);
            /* This is where I want it to wait for 1 second */
            crossfade(mainLayout, wrongLayout, animationDuration);
```

and the crossfade method-

```
private void crossfade(View fadeInLayout, final View fadeOutLayout,
            int animationDuration) {
          // Set the content view to 0% opacity but visible, so that it is visible
        // (but fully transparent) during the animation.
        fadeInLayout.setAlpha(0f);
        fadeInLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Animate the content view to 100% opacity, and clear any animation
        // listener set on the view.
        fadeInLayout.animate()
                .alpha(1f)
                .setDuration(animationDuration)
                .setListener(null);

        // Animate the loading view to 0% opacity. After the animation ends,
        // set its visibility to GONE as an optimization step (it won't
        // participate in layout passes, etc.)
        fadeOutLayout.animate()
                .alpha(0f)
                .setDuration(animationDuration)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        fadeOutLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found this post which deals with just about the same problem-

[Why the Sleep executes first and than the code above it in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854039/why-the-sleep-executes-first-and-than-the-code-above-it-in-android)

I've changed the appropriate execution function and now it seems to work properly, though I'm still puzzled by the fact that I cannot cause the code to stop at a designated location for a specific amount of time. Oh well...